# Interface/Type from field values of an array of objects?

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form

I want to create a React hook form builder component. It takes an array of field configs, and renders the corresponding form. But I can't figure out how to define the prop types.

The [document](https://react-hook-form.com/ts/) shows we should pass `FormValues` to `useForm` (`useForm<FormValues>`), but since the component takes in any number of field configs, I don't know how to define `FormValues`.

```
// form field
type FormField = {
  name: string;
  ...
}
```

```
// component props
type ComponentProps = {
  fields: Array<FormField>;
  onSubmit: SubmitHandler;
  onError: SubmitErrorHandler;
  defaultValues: FormValues; // !!!here!!!
}
```

Is it possible to define `FormValues` from the value of `name` field of an array of `FormField`? Something like this?

```
type FormValues = {
  [fieldName: values of Array<FormField>.name]: string | number
}
```

Or can I do this with generic type?

===================

To be more specific, for example if the component got

```
const fields: FormField[] = [
  {
    name: "username", label...
  },
  {
    name: "email", ...
  }
]
```

then the default values should be:

```
type FormValues = {
  username?: string;
  email?:string
}
const defaultValues:FormValues = {
  username: "some name",
  email: "test@test.com"
}
```

And the variables are used like `<FormComponent fields={fields} defaultValues={defaultValues}>`

Then inside the component,

```
const {control, setValue,...} = useForm<FormValue>({defaultValues})

return (
<form>
  {fields.map(field) => ...} // render fields
</form>
)
```

BTW, I've managed to build this component with js, but have no success with types...

Comment: Its unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Do you want a generic type for the `fieldName` which could be `one of the corresponding value of name key` in the type `FormField` ?

Comment: are you looking for this?
`type FormValues = {
  [k: FormField['name']]: string | number
}`